# Is it ok to have multiple subscriptions for Angular form.valueChanges()?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, subscription, angular-forms

I have a Auto save form which has a `debounceTime(500)` for saving values. But, I have some conditions for the values which I want to effect immediately upon form ValueChange. Since, I have a debounceTime I am using another valueChanges subscription to do this. Is this a right way to do it or Is there a better way to do this?

```js
form.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(500), takeUntil(destroyed$)).subscribe((value) => save(value));
form.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(destroyed$)).subscribe((value) => {
  if (!value) {
    return;
  }

  //Some condtions to change the values
  this.convertDateToUTC(value.date); // example only
});
```

Comment: iirc valueChanges doesn't emit initial value but you can stick a `startWith(this.form.getRawValue())` / `startWith(this.form.value)` in the pipe  stream to force a first emission

Comment: You could do it all in a single pipe. You can do you date conversion using `tap`. Read more here: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap

Comment: Like @MichaelBeeson already said, you can `tap` before `debounceTime` and save (without delay). Date conversion can also be done using the `map` operator, but I suspect that the `convertDateToUTC` function is impure and it actually manipulates state.

Comment: @MichaelBeeson When used tap() I can manipulate the data but it is not reflected right away on the form. Let's say I have a radio button formControl and upon valueChange it adds or removes some form fields and the user can fill the fields.